# segmentation fault scrabble game

Tags: c++

im working on a little scrabblegame which i read a txtfile and create a hashtable for all words inside. Word is a specific class which contains a vector of . 
i want to create a hashmap by my own and define the length of my "Dictionary" is 50000. im using a nullpointer to reserve all index of my array. If i want to print to my hashtable, compiler tells me a segmentation fault. does any one seems the error?

```
the headerfile:
    class Dictionary {
    public:
        Dictionary();
        Dictionary(string filepath);
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Dictionary& obj);
        bool find(const Word& word);
        vector<Word> allPossibleWords(const vector<Character>& tiles);

        //    struct compare {
        //
        //        bool operator()(const Word& a, const Word& b) {
        //            return a.operator<(b);
        //        }
        //    } myCompare;

        vector<Word> m_allWords;
        vector<Word>::iterator itVecWords;
        static const int table_size = 500000;
        //    std::array <Word*, table_size> arrWords = {nullptr};
        Word* arrWords[table_size] = {nullptr};
        int hash(Word new_word);
        void addItem(Word word);
        void printHashTable();



    the cpp:
    Dictionary::Dictionary(string filepath) {

    ifstream datei(filepath.c_str());
    while (datei.good() && !datei.eof()) {
        string temp;
        string temp1;
        string::size_type pos;
        getline(datei, temp);
        pos = temp.find(" ");
        temp1 = temp.substr(0, pos);
        Word new_word(temp1);
        addItem(new_word);
    }
    datei.close();



}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Dictionary& obj) {
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.m_allWords.size(); i++) {
        os << obj.m_allWords[i] << endl;
    }
    return os;
}

bool Dictionary::find(const Word& word) const {
    if (std::binary_search(m_allWords.begin(), m_allWords.end(), word)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

vector<Word> Dictionary::allPossibleWords(const vector<Character>& tiles) const {

    vector<Word> ergebnis;


    string tmp;
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < tiles.size(); i++) {
        tmp += tiles[i].GetC();
    }

    sort(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());


    for (int i = 1; i <= tiles.size(); i++) {
        do {
            string piece = tmp.substr(0, i);
            do {
                Word search = Word(piece);
                //Überschreibt immer der in Ergebnis existierte Wert
                if (find(search) && std::find(ergebnis.begin(), ergebnis.end(), search) == ergebnis.end()) {
                    ergebnis.push_back(search);
                }

            } while (next_permutation(piece.begin(), piece.end()));
        } while (next_permutation(tmp.begin(), tmp.end()));
    }

    return ergebnis;

}

int Dictionary::hash(Word new_word) {
    int index = 0;
    for (auto u : new_word.new_Character) {
        index += (int) u.GetC();
    }
    index = index * (int) new_word.new_Character.at(0).GetC();
    index = index * (int) new_word.new_Character.at(new_word.new_Character.size() - 1).GetC();
    return index % table_size;

}

void Dictionary::addItem(Word word) {

    int index = hash(word);
    if (arrWords[index] == nullptr) {
        arrWords[index] = new Word(word);
    } else {
        Word* ptr = arrWords[index];
        Word* neu = new Word(word);
        while (ptr->getNextWord() != nullptr) {
            ptr = ptr->getNextWord();
        }
        ptr->setNextWord(neu);
    }

}

void Dictionary::printHashTable() {

    Word* tmp;
    for (int i = 0; i < table_size; i++) {
        tmp = arrWords[i];
        if (tmp != nullptr) {
            tmp->printWord();
            cout << "Index : " << i;
        }

        tmp = tmp->getNextWord();
    }

}

class Word {
public:
    Word();
    Word(string m_wort);

    int length() const; 
    int points() const; 
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Word& obj);
    bool operator==(const Word& right) const; /
    bool operator!=(const Word& right) const; 
    bool contains(const Character& c) const; 
    Word substr(int start, int end) const; 
    bool operator<(const Word& right) const;

    vector <Character> new_Character;

    Word* Next = nullptr;
    void setNextWord(Word*);
    Word* getNextWord();
    void printWord();
    string getWordAsString();


CPP File:
    void Word::setNextWord(Word* w) {

        Next = w;
    }

    Word* Word::getNextWord() {

        return Next;

    }

    void Word::printWord() {
        string s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < new_Character.size(); i++) {
            s += new_Character.at(i).GetC();
        }
        cout << s << endl;

    }

    string Word::getWordAsString() {
        string s;
        for (int i = 0; i < new_Character.size(); i++) {
            s += new_Character.at(i).GetC();
        }
        return s;
    }
```

Comment: run it under a debugger

Comment: `gdb` is your best friend

Comment: https://beej.us/guide/bggdb/

Comment: Where is 'getNextWord()'?

Comment: its a return function in class word. Its a nullpointer

Comment: @JoeGeoffrey Does it always return nullptr?

Comment: yes it should be.  i defined it like here  Word* Next = nullptr;

Comment: `Word* neu = new Word(word);` -- Why did you resort to using pointers?  What is wrong with just adding a `Word` object instead of a pointer?  Introducing pointers increases the chances you will get segmentation faults.  Also, you're passing `Word` by value -- please post the `Word` class, as passing by value invokes a copy, and we don't know if `Word` has correct copy semantics.